# Integral and sum function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, solution-verification

I have that
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{1}{1+n^2}\right)e^{inx}\right)\text{.}$$
Where $f$ is the sumfunction for the serie.
Then I have to find
$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\,sin(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\,cos(x)\mathrm{d}x$.
I think I can find it without finding the sumfunction. Maybe swap the sum and integral?
I think:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{e^{inx}}{1+n^2}cos(x)\right)dx\right)\text{}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{2nsin(n\pi)}{n^4-1}\right)\text{}=\pi$$
Is that correct? And how can I formally show it? For $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\,sin(x)\mathrm{d}x$ I got a expression with complex (with i). How can I deal with that sum?

Answer (score 2):

The interchange of sum and integral is justified by uniform convergence. The series is uniformly convergent by M-test since $|e^{inx}|=1$ and $\sum \frac 1 {1+n^{2}} <\infty$. You have found $\int f(x) \cos x dx$ correctly but there are mistakes in what you have written. You cannot have $n^{4}-1$ in the denominator because $n=1$ is included in the sum.  Try to re-write your calculation.

For  $\int f(x) \sin x dx$ the answer is $i\pi$ and this is surely a complex number.

If $f$ was real valued you would get a real number for the integral but our function $f$ is complex valued so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Nice, thank you, that make sense. It makes sense that we can't have $^2$−1 in the denominator when n=1 is included in the sum. But I can't see how I can rewrite the calculation? Can you help me?

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{inx} \cos xdx=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos (nx) \cos xdx+i\int_0^{2\pi} \sin (nx) \cos xdx$ use then formulas $\cos A \cos B=(\cos (A+B) +\cos (A-B)) /2$ and $\sin A \cos B=(\sin (A+B) +\sin (A-B)) /2$ to calculate the integrals. @Lifeni